# Jquery split function exception

Tags: jquery

I am facing a bit weird problem while splitting out a string in jQuery. For some reason I am getting following exception

**TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'split'**

i have attached one image that displays the data n exception on browser.
n[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```
**skill List contains [Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4],
```

Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], 
Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]] 
and every array has following structure** 
    0: Array[4]
    0: "NWDS"
    1: "NWDS "
    2: 1
    3: 1
    length: 4**

```
  $.each(skillsList, function(index, item) {
                var array = skillsList[index].split(',');

                });
```

Answer (score 3):

`skillList[index]` is an `Array[4]`. Arrays do not have the `split` function and therefore you're getting an error. You'll have to access one of the indeces of `skillList[index]` (eg `skillList[index][innerIndex]` in order to reach a `String`.